# Swap two UIButton using swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uibutton, gesture, swap

I have two UIButton on my view now. I would like to how to swap them. I already figure out how to using the swipe gesture. Just need help with swap their position with animation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not using autolayout, you can animate the swap with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect savedFrame = self.button1.frame;
                     self.button1.frame = self.button2.frame;
                     self.button2.frame = savedFrame;
                 }];
```